# selenium web driver error when trying to run a script on eclipse

Tags: selenium

I am getting this error when I try to run a script in eclipse using Selenium webdriver:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
>   version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:56'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45' Connection to 127.0.0.1:7055 refused

What could be the problem?

Comment: Four things: Update Selenium: `Build info: version: '2.33.0'`, Why are you giving us old log files: `time: '2013-05-22 15:32:56'`, against what browser are you running this test and finally, what version of that browser is it?

Comment: Using firefox browser , ver -17.1.0

Comment: The other two questions?!!!